# css: is it possible to move the child elements inside the parent element so that the parent element is automatically resized

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

Do you know if it is possible not to "manually" set the exact size of the parent block by moving the child blocks inside the parent block (using `position: relative; left: xxx;` or `transform: translate()`)?

I gave an example - you can see that the moved block goes beyond the bottom border of the parent block and does not reach the right border of the parent block

but I would like the elements to fit exactly into the parent block

i can do it by manually setting coordinates and size, but can it be done only with css automatically?

```css
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .group {
        display: inline-block;
        
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;

        font-size: 0;
        
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .group div {
        font-size:  20px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .group div:not(.main) {
        width:  128px;
        height: 128px;
        
        border: 1px solid red;
        background: lime;
    }
    
    .main {
        transform: translate(-20px, 20px);
        
        width:  192px;
        height: 192px;
        
        border: 1px solid blue;
        background: orange;
```

```html
<div class = 'group'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div class = 'main'>3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: move it with margin?

Comment: @Temani Afif, no, no, I need the boundaries of the parent block to strictly touch the child blocks without any gaps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to compensate for the `translate` of the child in the margins of the parent, thus canceling any gaps.

Note: I took the liberty of cleaning the code, eliminating unnecessary values and also making the solution more clear. Hope it work for you.

Edit: This solution do not require `float` which could be a problem. Also, you can use `position: relative` instead of `transform` without any problems.

```css
div {
  display: table;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  /* same amount as the transform to compensate */
  margin-right: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

div > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  background: lightgreen;
}

div > div:last-child {
  width: 192px;
  height: 192px;
  
/* use this and delete the transform if you like:
      position: relative;
      right: 20px;
      top: 20px;    
*/
  
  transform: translate(-20px, 20px);
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the child divs to float and then moving the last one with margins.

```css
.group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.group div {
  font-size:  20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.group div:not(.main) {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: lime;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
        
  width:  192px;
  height: 192px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class = 'group'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div class = 'main'>3</div>
</div>
```

Note that this is only a solution for your exact question, meaning it will fit the right and the bottom only.